# Rearrange the rows based on three conditions

Tags: excel, vba

I have product sku in column A, weight in column B, dimension in column C and location where they are placed in column D. Now, i want to reorder products in such a way that if either product dimension is greater than 0.16 and weight is greater than 5 and location contains CL anywhere, it moves the product to column adjacent to the location that does not contain CL and move other products accordingly.
I am trying to create a slotting method.

Thanks.

[image]

I tried writing a code but it does not work rather it deletes the rows. I was expecting that location will remain static and column A to D will rearrange themselves.
| SKU     | Description         | Dimensions | Weight | Location    |
|---------|---------------------|------------|--------|-------------|
| 4457201 | BUL CHOC FUDGE BARS | 0.05       | 3.25   | 10:CL-B-004 |
| 1647164 | MR KIP LEMON SLICE  | 0.06       | 2.89   | 10:CL-A-005 |
| 6893736 | MAGNUM CLASSIC      | 0.06       | 3.00   | 10:CL-B-005 |
| 9933564 | CL MINI CROISS 8PK  | 0.10       | 4.00   | 10:CL-C-005 |
| 9131290 | SL FRN CRM CHSECKE  | 0.05       | 3.00   | 10:CL-A-006 |
| 5070637 | MC CP BB STEAKFRIE  | 0.08       | 10.00  | 10:CL-B-006 |
**| 1597180 | CL BAH WHT DNR RLL  | 0.15       | 6.00   | 10:CL-C-006 |**
Result:
| SKU     | Description          | Dimensions | Weight | Location    |
|---------|----------------------|------------|--------|-------------|
| 4314995 | ING CR BREA NUGGETS  | 0.05       | 2.59   | 10:CL-B-009 |
| 6050216 | CALIP MNI RPSB PNE   | 0.05       | 4.10   | 10:CL-C-009 |
**| 1597180 | CL BAH WHT DNR RLL   | 0.15       | 6.00   | 10:02-C-072 |**
| 5293289 | CL ORIG CHICK TENDRS | 0.08       | 2.41   | 10:02-A-072 |
| 7213575 | PT LIFE SVR 5 FLAV   | 0.08       | 4.30   | 10:02-C-071 |
| 9486411 | BUL CC CKIE CREAM    | 0.10       | 7.00   | 10:02-A-071 |

In the result it should move the products and it's information to the next nearest location which does not contain CL. and moved rest rows up.

Code:
Sub SlottingPlan()

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Long
Dim dimension_threshold As Double
Dim weight_threshold As Double

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("new")
Set rng = ws.Range("A2:F" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row)

dimension_threshold = 0.16
weight_threshold = 5

For row = rng.row To rng.Rows.Count + rng.row - 1

    'check if the product's dimension or weight exceeds the threshold
    If IsNumeric(rng.Cells(row, "C").Value) And rng.Cells(row, "C").Value > dimension_threshold _
    Or IsNumeric(rng.Cells(row, "D").Value) And rng.Cells(row, "D").Value > weight_threshold Then
    
        'check if column F contains 4
        If rng.Cells(row, "F").Value = 4 Then
        
            'move the row to the next row where column F is not 4
            Do Until Not IsNumeric(rng.Cells(row, "F").Value) Or rng.Cells(row, "F").Value <> 4 Or row >= rng.Rows.Count + rng.row - 1
                row = row + 1
            Loop
            
        End If
        
    End If
    
    'do other operations on the product if it does not meet the condition above
    '...

Next row
```

End Sub

Comment: Please share your code if you need help with it.

Comment: I am trying to share the code but it too long

Comment: Please use [Table Markdown](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#) copy from excel, generate it and copy it back to your question. It doesn't seem to be clear your expected output, please provide it as part of your question.

Comment: | SKU     | Description         | Dimensions | Weight | Location    |
|---------|---------------------|------------|--------|-------------|
| 5070637 | MC CP BB STEAKFRIE  | 0.08       | 10.00  | 10:CL-B-006 |
| 1597180 | CL BAH WHT DNR RLL  | 0.15       | 6.00   | 10:CL-C-006 | now in this case weight is greater than 6 and location contains cl so i want to move whole row from sku to weight adjacent to a location which does not contain CL and move anything below this row up to have continuity

Comment: Instead of trying to add these things in comments, edit your question instead. Comment have limitations. https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Just curious, you say : _ if either product dimension is greater than 0.16 **and** weight is greater than 5_. But in the code you use "OR" ? `If IsNumeric(rng.Cells(row, "C").Value) And rng.Cells(row, "C").Value > dimension_threshold _
    Or IsNumeric(rng.Cells(row, "D").Value) And rng.Cells(row, "D").Value > weight_threshold Then`. Please CMIIW.

Comment: You wrote : _I have product sku in column A, weight in column B, dimension in column C and location where they are placed in column D_. So, in what column is "Description" ? Also, your table data in the image is 5 column (I assume from column A to E), but in your code you have _'check if column F contains 4_. Anyway, if there is no 4 in column F at all, are you expecting that your 'do loop' won't give any result even if the previous IF meet the criteria ? Please CMIIW.

Comment: i was trying to make it easier to identify which locations have CL in them. i added column f as a check but still code is not working